# Hardware-Software synchonization with clock in a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, uart, clock

From what I understand, there is a clock in a micro-controller, and every little task is executed at a clock pulse.

Can two or more actions be performed simultaneously (In the same clock pulse)?

For example, assume two lines of code. In line 1 I send some data to the UART data register (assume assembly code so there is 1-1 correspondence with clock and command, it is not the point here).

Now, what happens on the next clock?

- Is line 2 executed and the fist bit of the data register is moved to FIFO at the same clock pulse?
- Is line 2 executed and all 8-bits are moved from the data register to FIFO at the same clock pulse ?
- Or is execution of line 2 is postponed for some clocks pulses until all data are to FIFO ?

Comment: Which specific micro? Because it is impossible to say. If you have a 400 MHz CPU core, and the UART is on 100 MHz peripheral bus, somewhere must be a wait state.

Comment: Say both the peripheral bus and the CPU core run on 400MHz, how would it work then ? (I use the Tiva™ TM4C123GH6PM Microcontroller.)

Comment: There is no generic answer how it works. Depends on how the UART peripheral works too.

Comment: So it is possible option 2 to be the case ( line 2 is executed and all 8 bits to move to FIFO at the same clock pulse) ?

Comment: Option 2 is the most likely, yes. In general all the peripheral blocks work independently and can all do things on the same cycle.

Comment: That's a MCU with cortex-M4 core. Usually those do not run the peripheral buses at same frequency than core, but I am not familiar with this specific MCU. Data register is 8 bits so each byte is written as whole, so 8 bits at a time is written, not 1 bit at a time.

Comment: @pcj50 So it is ok in most of the cases to think each module as independent and  a single module capable of performing one thing at each cycle ?

Comment: @kot No. This is too general a question. Alongside the CPU are peripherals. Some peripherals can carry out certain actions on their own once initiated, other actions require intervention from the CPU. Few peripherals run on as fast a clock as fast as the CPU does and as a result off clocks that are slower than the CPU. So one cycle for the CPU might not even correspond to one cycle for the peripheral. Presumably everything tries to do useful for its own clock cycle...unless it's waiting on data from somewhere else.

Comment: If you really want to know how this works I'd recommend watching entire series of "Building an 8-bit breadboard computer" videos on [Ben Eater's channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCS0N5baNlQWJCUrhCEo8WlA). Even though modern MCUs are much more complex, the basic principles remain the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I understand, there is a clock in a micro-controller, and every little task is executed at a clock pulse.

At least one clock.  Modern microcontrollers may have more than one, and numerous clocks derived from the one master clock.

> Question: Can two or more actions be performed simultaneously (In the same clock pulse) ?

*Can* they?  Yes.  *Are* they?  Often, but not always.

> For example, assume two lines of code. In line 1 I send some data to the UART data register (assume assembly code so there is 1-1 correspondence with clock and command,it is not the point here).
>
> Now, what happens on the next clock?

Slow down!

- If your "lines of code" are in C, Python, or some other higher-level language, then each line of code usually represents multiple machine instructions.  One line of code could compile to anything from zero to hundreds of machine instructions.
- Modern processors (like the ARM Cortex cores) are pipelined, so you can have multiple instructions in play at once (do a web search).

So what happens on the "next clock" is generally that the next machine instruction generated by the compiler from that line of code (or kicked off by the interpreter, if it's Python or similar) executes.  *Eventually* that line finishes.

> Is line 2 executed and the fist bit of the data register is moved to FIFO at the same clock pulse?
>
> Is line 2 executed and all 8-bits are moved from the data register to FIFO at the same clock pulse ?

In that particular processor, the core "thinks" it's just writing out to memory.  The UART is connected in a manner called "memory mapped", which means that all the UART registers appear to be plain old memory -- it's up to you to tell the compiler that they're not (in C you'd use various directives like `volatile` and `const`; if you're using a vendor's library that ought to be taken care of for you).

When you write a word to the UART's transmit register, the UART takes care of the rest, independently of the core.  When it's done, there are various mechanisms of notifying the core (the simplest and most intrusive being that you poll a bit in your code; the hardest and least intrusive being that you set the UART and your code to interrupt the core when a byte is finished transmitting).

Note that an alternative method for doing this job involves the processor "manually" sending out bits on a general-purpose I/O pin.  This is called "bit banging"; it uses a *lot* of processor resources for the intelligence used, but it can make sense if you have a teeny processor doing an even teenier job.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one clock if not multiples usually derived from that clock.  Just look at the documentation for the part, look at one of the stm32s there is a nice chart of the clock tree.

The uart is not driven by assembly language the cpu and the uart and the i2c and the flash and the ram and the timers and the.... are all separate modules, all are driven by some clock.  you write a value to an address in the processor core the processor puts that out on its bus, there is a memory/bus controller on the other side that may or may not be logic from the same vendor (for example in an stm32 or anything with a cortex-m arm made the core but the chip vendor or someone else makes the logic for the rest of the chip) then the address is decoded and so on, the cpu is done, game over it has moved on to other things, fire and forget.  That write works its way toward the uart.  lands in a fifo or holding register or possibly straight to the shift register depending on the uart design (dont assume any two are the same in any way).  the peripheral clock that feeds the uart may be dozens or hundreds of times faster than the programmed/desired baud rate and you need to get a start bit out and you need to finish whatever else was shifting out so one to dozens or thousands of clocks after the cpu took some data and some address (that address means nothing to the cpu btw it is just bits it only means something to the system) that first data bit of that write to the uart starts to shift out.  one to thousands of clocks later the second bit goes out.

the processor does not execute one instruction per clock, certainly not in an mcu, nor any other processor, it might average with a pipeline on a good day for short bursts of instructions but an mcu often has wait states on the flash, some are 2x slower than the processor at best then when you up the speed of the system clock/cpu clock the flash has to have more wait states added, so you arent running one clock per instruction even if it were possible.  how pipelines work and if your cpu even has one, etc, is a whole other topic.

processors dont execute assembly code they execute machine code.